# Does this site need questions-collections of books\puzzles?

Tags: discussion

There are nice community wiki post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), which I find very usefull.

Does this site need something like this? Collection of good books on puzzles? Articles? Puzzles themselves? Solutions? (I dislike presenting solutions for general access, but the question is still valid).

This is also refers to the question "How do we attract people on this site?"

P.S. For example, I found the link to article at [Variation of 100 prisoners light problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/394/variation-of-100-prisoners-light-problem) question very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Community reference questions aren't unheard of on Stack Exchange, and I won't preclude the possibility that we encounter a use for such a community wiki question. However, they're *exceedingly* rare, and I've only ever seen them used when there's strong community support for it. It's really up to the community as a whole to decide when and where they would be useful, but we should be very careful about these.

The examples you provide are rather broad, and while they might be interesting, this might make them unwieldy for the community to maintain. If you think you have a good case for a *specific* question, then feel free to ask on Meta!

Ultimately, the community needs to decide whether such a question is worth the effort to maintain. If we decide it is, and decide that a community wiki question-and-answer is a good format for it, then we can go ahead and create it.

If you have a well-developed question you'd like to propose, simply ask whether it would be acceptable for the community on Meta. If you do have a question in mind that you'd like to have as a community references, there are a couple points it's a good idea to touch on:

- What content goes in the best answer(s) to the question?
- How much good content could go into the answer(s)?
- How much maintenance does it require from the community? (Is it worth it?)
- When would people in the wide, wide world actually be assisted by this question?

I'm sure there are other questions that I haven't mentioned here, but that's really the core of it. What it really boils down to is: "Will it ultimately be helpful to the community?"

Answer (score 0):

There are, or were, many, many more similar community wiki posts on Stack Overflow that do not remotely quality as nice. Indeed, the [C++ book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) was often touted in meta discussions on this topic as the example of how such questions worked — but there rarely was a second example. There are 104 deleted answers in the C++ list, almost all of them listing a single book, and most of them not giving much information as to why one would want to read that book. You can see that the [C book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) isn't nearly as nice — and it's still above average for such lists.

There is a place on the web for collections of links, but Stack Exchange isn't the place.